Project template "Monogame Android Application (MonoGame Team) produces non compilable project
When I have created a new project with the template Monogame Android Application (MonoGame Team), the following unresolved classes will be used by the generated code:

Activity
GraphicsDeviceManager
SpriteBatch
GraphicsDevice
ButtonState
AndroidGameActivity
View
LaunchMode

and some more...
What did I do wrong?
I have installed android studio and found Android SDK in
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Which I specify in the user environment variable ANDROID_HOME
The nuget packages that my new project will use are:

MonoGame.Framework.Android
MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task


This might belong there: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues

https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/8349 @MartinZeitler
